# Regular Expression: how to match least characters (non-greedy) but no less than N

Tags: regex, non-greedy

I want to have such a method leastMatch(String input, String regExp, int n)
input is the input text, regExp is the regular expression and n is the minimal amount of characters the result has.
The return value is a head of the input text which matches the regular expression and contain
at least n characters.

e.g.
    `leastMatch("abababab", "(ab)+", 3) //returns "abab"`
    `leastMatch("abababab", "(ab)+", 0) //returns ""`
    `leastMatch("abababab", "(ab)+", 4) //returns "abab"`

Answer (score 0):

use this syntaxe:

```
(ab){3,}    --> 3 or more
(ab){0,2}   --> less than 3
(ab){2,5}   --> between 2 and 5
(ab){3}     --> 3
```

you can easily determine the number of `ab` you allow with n and `ab` length (2 in this example)

Comment: it's not what I want. The regular expression is dynamic. Consider what if the regular expression is a*.